# Windows Server 2008 R2 Backup and Restore Best Practices

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, backup-restoration

What is the best practice for backing up a Windows Server 2008 R2 environment so that it can be restored to different hardware if need be with Active Directory etc. intact?

What needs to be considered in setting up the environment so that it can be recovered later and work correctly? In this case just two servers.

Can I just use the bare metal backup from wbadmin?

Answer (score 2):

What level of protection do you need? What are your RPO and RTO requirements? Only by responding to these questions, it may become possible to make a conclusion regarding the needed backup plan. Although for me, it is much better to approach any kind of design matter getting at least a rough idea on the way a solution should function after all.

Nevertheless, when it comes to backup best practices, a good old-fashioned 3-2-1 rule is coming to the fore:

https://www.veeam.com/blog/the-3-2-1-0-rule-to-high-availability.html

The most important thing is that if it is about a production environment and also if the workload that is under consideration, can be considered as a mission-critical one......

I'd definitely recommend referring to the solutions which have established their  place in the market. For starters, that implies Support and functionality capable of fitting you requirements tightly.

However, you do not need to go far in the process of searching for an appropriate solution. Veeam B&R is something that I'd like to address your attention to and BTW, it is all over the IT community. Worth checking IMHO!